# Marrying the mother of ex girlfriend

Tags: quran, nikah

Is it permissible for a man to marry the mother of a girl he used to have a relationship with? The relationship was in the past and involved physical touching but no penetration.

I understand from [4:23](http://quran.com/4/23) that marriage to the wife's mother is permanently prohibited from the time a man enters into a marriage contract with a woman, whether he and his wife have engaged in sexual intercourse or not. The act of marriage itself gives the mother-in-law the same status as the mother.

However in this case, the man never married the girl. Is her mother haram for him to marry?

Comment: Yes you can marry her since you weren't married to her daughter.

Comment: @Omar, I dunno if I can agree with that line of reasoning. Since the OP has mentioned that the man in question was involved in a physical relationship without penetration with the younger lady in question, the fact remains that it was a physical relationship. The Qur'an lists the mahrams that one cannot marry, so does that imply that one can do everything with any member of any of these mahram categories without marrying them? Secondly, a relationship of this sort may lead to a dysfunctional family owing to the fitnah that could potentially come about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is allowed for Muslim to marry mother of ex-girlfriend. In Islam, you don't have girlfriend and boyfriend relationship. You are married, or you are not. In this case, ex-girlfriend for her ex-boyfriend is like any other Muslim woman. So, since you can marry the mother of "any other woman" in Islam (who is not prohibited because of other reasons), you can marry the mother of ex girlfriend. Also, you can check [here](http://www.nikah.com/marriage/prohibited_marriage_partners.asp) for prohibited marriage partners. You'll see that there is no "mother of ex girlfriend" listed.

Comment: It is not true that "In Islam, you don't have girlfriend and boyfriend relationship."  We are living human and live in society and we might have friends

Comment: No one said that you cannot have friends. But the concept of "boyfriend" and "girlfriend" does not exist. You are either married or not (have "wife/husband" or not), there is nothing in-between.